# Floating Action Button still appearing on scroll even in ActionMode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I am using Google's Support Design Library for the FloatingActionButton, along with a CoordinatorLayout, RecyclerView, and CardView.

Everything works rather well, with the FAB disappearing on scroll and reappearing when the scroll ends.

I have one small issue however, and that is when I switch the recyclerview into multiselect mode. The FAB dissapears whenever the action mode is set, however scrolling the list view makes it reappear. Is there anyway to set the behavior for the FAB so that when the recycler view is in action mode(multiple selection), the FAB will not reappear when scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

There might be other ways to do this, but the most simplest way would be to set the visibility of the FAB to **"invisible"** in the `onCreateActionMode()` and back to **"visible"** in the `onDestroyActionMode()`.

```
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
 ... 
 fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 ...
 }

public boolean onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
 ... 
 fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 ...
 }
```

There is no way the FAB will show up in while the **CAB** is on. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already do that. The problem seems to be in the behavior. Whenever the CoordinatorLayout detects the RecyclerView Scroll, it fires the custom show/hide behavior. the problem being when it fires the show, even in action mode, it brings back the button.

Comment: I'm going to try something. looks like the View is passed in, I'm going to see if I can get a couple of properties from the view to determine whether to fire the behavior code or not.

Comment: Is your problem solved. It would be really good if you can accept my asnwer.